# what are the three skew lines to cross a ruling of a one-sheeted hyperboloid

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

As the book *Geometry and the Imagination* said, any one-sheeted hyperboloid is a ruled surface and a ruling (the line on the surface) crosses three skew lines (any two of them are not co-planar to each other). I am wondering what are the three skew lines to define a one-sheeted hyperboloid. For example, given the equation of a one-sheeted hyperboloic: $x^2+y^2−z^2 = 1$. What are the three skew lines that define the surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some elements of reflection.

[image]

First of all, this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2583247) of mine some years ago can be of some help. It deals with the determination of a ruled quadric knowing three of its 3 lines.

Preliminary material: let us recall how 2 families of skew lines generating a given hyperboloid with one sheet can be obtained.

Dealing with the example you give, with equation written under the form

$$y^2-z^2=1-x^2 \ \iff $$

$$\text{Surface} \ H \ : (y-z)(y+z)=(1-x)(1+x),\tag{1}$$

the two families of lines can be given the following equations:

$$\text{Lines} \  L_a : \ \begin{cases}y-z&=&a(1-x)\\y+z&=&\dfrac{1}{a}(1+x)\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

$$\text{Lines} \  L'_b : \ \begin{cases}y-z&=&b(1+x)\\y+z&=&\dfrac{1}{b}(1-x)\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

for any non-zero real number $a$ or $b$.

Remark: please note that, by multiplication of its 2 equations, (2) $\implies$ (1) ; implication of equations meaning inclusion of corresponding geometric entities ($\forall a, L_a \subset H$) as desired. For the same reason, $\forall b, L'_b \subset H$.

$H$ can be defined by selecting any 3 lines of a family, say $L_{a_1},L_{a_2},L_{a_3}$ or 2 in a family and the third in the other one.

But taking only two of these lines, for example $L_1$ and $L'_1$:

$$L_1 : \ \begin{cases}y-z&=&1-x\\y+z&=&1+x\end{cases} \ \text{and} \ L'_1 : \ \begin{cases}y-z&=&1+x\\y+z&=&1-x\end{cases}\tag{4}$$

whose intersection point is $(x,y,z)=(0,1,0)$ is not enough to define in a unique way a hyperboloid with one sheet (think for example, among other solutions, to the hyperboloid with one sheet symmetrical to $H$ with respect to the plane defined by $L_1 \cup L'_1$). Besides, there are other candidates: there exists Hyperbolic Paraboloids that can pass through these 2 lines.

Comment: No comment ? Maybe you are looking for a different type of answer ? In this case, please say it.

Comment: No, what I needed is the equations of the three skew lines that all intersect with a family of rulings on the surface. Not the rulings themselves here.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what you mean; when you say "for another surface" do you mean another hyperboloid with one sheet ? And why 3 lines ? I am going to add a figure to my answer : it could help for dialog...

Comment: Maybe, could you give the excerpt of the book (unless one can find it online) ?

Comment: At p.15, please see the book link: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Geometry_and_the_Imagination/7WY5AAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=geometry+and+imagination&printsec=frontcover  Another excerpt from the web page page: "the union of the lines meeting three lines 2 by 2 non-coplanar and non-parallel to a fixed plane" from this link may help as well: https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/hyperboloid/hyperboloid1.shtml

Comment: After some trials, it seems i found the three skew lines to a ruling of the surface $x^2 + z^2 - y^2 =1$ (another hyperboloid of one sheet). The surface's rulings surely intersect with all three skew lines simutaneously.

Comment: An interesting reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1204689

Answer (score 0):

After some random trials, I found one member of a family of rulings ($\frac{x}{-1} = \frac{y-1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{z-\sqrt{2}}{1}$) to the hyperboloid of one-sheet ($x^2 + z^2 - y^2 = 1$) truly intersects with the following three skew lines:
$$\frac{x}{1} = \frac{y}{1} = \frac{z-1}{0},\frac{x}{1} = \frac{y}{-1} = \frac{z+1}{0},\frac{x+1}{0} = \frac{y}{1} = \frac{z}{1} $$

Comment: But you can find not only 3 but an infinity of such lines! In fact, the initial line being member of one of the families, it will intersect **all** lines of the other family. I definitely not understand your interpretation of the result given in the book.

Comment: You are right. The skew lines are actually the rulings themselves from different families. Thanks for mentioning this! @Jean Marie

Comment: Take a look at this deep "survey": http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~olegviro/skewlines.pdf